# Android unit tests - SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: Attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I just created unit tests for my CRUD implementations and I have this weird problem. When tests are run one by one, they all pass. But when I want to run the whole suite, they fail with the error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1367)
at cz.pikadorama.simpleorm.DatabaseSanityTest.testDelete(DatabaseSanityTest.java:55)
```

Here's the code

```
@Before
public void prepareDatabase() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    DbManager.registerHelper(new TestSQLiteHelper(context), new Class<?>[]{TestEntity.class});
}

@Test
public void testDelete() {
    Dao<TestEntity> dao = DaoManager.getDao(TestEntity.class);
    TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
    dao.create(entity);  
    dao.delete(entity);
    assertEquals(0, dao.findAll().size());
}

// other tests for insert, update, ... follow
```

By the way, DAO implementations always open writable database as `sqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: Are you closing the database at any point between your tests?

Comment: Try to change your current `@Before` method into `@BeforeClass` method. Does it resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, in the end I tried to move the prepare to `@BeforeClass` and cleaned the database instead of deleting it before each test.

Comment: So, it did resolve the issue, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the fact that DbManager and DaoMaster are singletons (as well as the underlying database, I suppose): the code in `@Before` is called before each test, which screws up things in classes which, probably, should be initiated just once.

Change `@Before` annotation to `@BeforeClass` in order to perform the initialization just once.

Comment: Well, that's not the problem. The issue is that when you have delete database in `@Before` and you run it each time, the tests are so fast the actually there is a 'hot journal' that needs to be written. But by default the Java connection is created as read-only and you cannot write the journal with that connection.

Comment: @user219882, I think you are mistaken. You can delete database in `@Before`, but then you must make sure that you also initialize it properly again. I do think that the issue in your case was the fact that a call to `DbManager.registerHelper()` did not do the initialization properly. In any case, since this answer resolved your issue, consider accepting it )